# How to filter arrays with a for loop without the filter function?

Tags: javascript

Our task is to write a function which filters a list of human names. The result should be only names without a hyphen ("-").

The only ideas I have till now:

```
let names = ['Marc', 'Stephen-Peter', 'Lisa', 'Marie-Tina', 'Philip']; 


function filter (arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ??????;
    }
    return ???;
}

console.log(???); 

//The result should be only Marc, Lisa, Philip
```

My ideas were to use charAt and check every word for a "-" but then I don't know how to prevent that the whole name with the hyphen is not inside the new filtered array. I thought about two for loops I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Create a new empty array. In your loop, check if there is no hyphen (look at the `includes` method) and push the element into the new array in that case. At the end return the new array.

Comment: Show your efforts. I mean if you don't even know what to put for the `???` in `console.log`, then all hope is lost. But also the remaining part: don't just copy the template code you evidently got in your assignment. Show what you have researched and tried.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I didn't knew about the includes method and tried it with `names[i].charAt(i) == "-"` but it did not work.

The code I posted was not the code I got in the assignment. The assignment was without code examples. Sorry for not posting my code ideas and forgetting to enclose the names as strings. I'm physiotherapist and had nothing to do with programming and it's not that easy for me to understand everything. I'm trying the best I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first the array items need to be inside single or double quotes
let names = ['Marc', 'Stephen-Peter', 'Lisa', 'Marie-Tina', 'Philip'];

```
 function filter (arr) {
        let result = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           if(!arr[i].includes('-')) {              
               result.push(arr[i])
           }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    console.log(filter(names))
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on your idea, i think you just need to use an if condition and a new array to which you pass the filtered values.

```js
let names = ['Marc', 'Stephen-Peter', 'Lisa', 'Marie-Tina', 'Philip']; 


function filter (arr) {
     let ans =[];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].indexOf('-') === -1)
          ans.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return ans;
}

console.log(filter(names));
```

PS: Your list of names were not string enclosed. Please ensure you do that whenever posting a ques/ans. Also try to use code snippets.